# Blazor; creating a list with possible links

Tags: blazor

Building a Blazor 3.1 app (prototyping a server and client, so wanting a solution for both). I was trying to figure out a simple way of doing this, but it seemed harder than expected.

Getting a list of sentence strings from a service, I wanted to display them in an unordered list.
Before I add the text to the list item, I want to add links if there is a recognizable word.

So if the lines of text say

- "Last week at Microsoft, we built something great"
- "People at Stackoverflow are really helpful, especially with Microsoft code issues"

I want the result to be

```
<ul>
<li>Last week at <a href='www.microsoft.com'>Microsoft</a>, we built something great</li>
<li>People at <a href='www.stackoverflow .com'>Stackoverflow </a> are really helpful, especially with <a href='www.microsoft.com'>Microsoft</a> code issues<li>
</ul>
```

I could tweak it using JavaScript, but I'd think there was a way to do it without JS.
Components no longer have an override for BuildRenderTree, so I can't do that.

I can't assume there is a keyword that I'd need to create a link, so each line of text could have 0 to many hrefs.
I can't make a component that used `<pre>`, since it is part of an unordered list and `<pre>` is a block-line element and I'd prefer no to do extra CSS.

Comment: What if you set up a Dictionary<string, string> that holds the keywords as keys and links WITH <a> tags as values, then use the c# String.Replace method to iterate through your sentence list and search by key, replace with value? Then iterate your updated list as the <li> elements? Depending on how many sentences and links, there could be some time complexity for sure, but this would get it done.

Comment: Thanks Nik, but the issue isn't the Dictionary, the question is more how to dynamically create the links. With normal Razor ASP code it isn't a problem - because you can create new HTML elements about output them. With Blazor it seems between the pre-release and now they've removed the RenderFragment aspect?
I don't know how many lines I have, and I don't know how many links on any given line I have - I'm asking Blazor people how would you do it?

Comment: I found my own answer, to display some markup there is **MarkupString**. Using that I can parse my input and insert links and then just use

`<li>@((MarkupString)@line)</li>`

My use is fairly simple, but for those that might have more complex scenarios, one might try to tweak your text and inject Markdown, and then can use the  [Markdig package](https://www.codemag.com/Article/1811071/Marking-up-the-Web-with-ASP.NET-Core-and-Markdown)

Comment: And FYI, I can use **MarkupString** in my Blazor apps, and **HtmlString** in my Razor app, so the same idea will work for different projects, just different markup helper

Comment: I see that in the blazor docs now, it's so short I'm not surprised I missed it so many times. That does exactly what needs to be done. Enter it as the answer to your own question, get some upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, I found out myself the solution was to use **MarkupString** (for Blazor apps, and **HtmlString** for a Razor app)